# Google Translate top part always stays

Tags: html, google-translate

When I use Google Translate, the top portion always stays even when I click on a link to go to another page. How is that possible? What HTML can make this happen?

Comment: How is it used? Could you explain a little?

Comment: @lonut - they are not using `iframe`, its `ajax`

Comment: @MiniGod OP asked "What HTML can make this happed?" iframe is html, ajax is not

Comment: @IonutHulub fair enough, but google translate it not using ´iframe´.

Comment: @lonutHulub often OP doesn't know how to express what it is they want, the whole reason they are asking is because they don't know how something works and therefore probably don't know all the terminology.  The best we can do is offer up solutions we feel are good solutions to the problem.  IMO mentioning both ajax and iframes is the best option and explaining a bit about both is even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what part you are talking about however websites use several tricks to achieve page switching without reloading.

iframes can be used to include other pages within your page, this can in some cases give the effect you are looking for.

Many modern pages will use ajax, this will load some data via an asynchronous javascript call which is then used to populate part of a page, this means the whole page does not need to be refreshed.